# How to analyse this fitted vs data (actual) scatter plot

Tags: r, linear-regression, scatter-plot, data-fitting, multivariate-time-series

How to interpret this fitted vs data(actual) plot? My data is time series and there are many observations for the y variable for one year.
[scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf7Uw.png)

how to analyse it if my data is a time series one?
This is a multiple linear regression model
Please see the photo that I have inserted 'scatter plot'. I am kinda confused on how to analyse it. Thank you.

Comment: Please explain what the data is meant to be. The plot seems to be inconsistent: Apparently the "predicted values" are discrete (categorial or ordinal), whereas the "actual values" seem to be continuous (numeric).

Comment: This is not really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you need help interpreting results from statistical models or choosing how to analyze your data, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. You are likely to get better help there.